# How to pass a JSON Array in a parent child communication in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, parent-child

I am new in VueJS and I have some problems with JSON file and parent-child communication.
I need to pass each array that's in JSON file to child Vue Element.

In my mind, the parent reads the JSON file and with v-for, creates a child, one for each array in the JSON file.

I don't find anything online, and with props, I can't do this.
Please, help me!!

I need to pass the 'firstArray' (Array of Objects) from parent to child .vue files.

**This is my JSON file:**

```
{
  "firstArray": [
    {"id": 01, "name": "Lucas"},
    {"id": 02, "name": "Michael"}
  ],

  "secondArray": [
    {"id": 01, "name": "Maria"},
    {"id": 02, "name": "Taylor"}
  ],

  ...
}
```

**This is the parent .vue file to read the name of Array in a JSON file:**

```
<template>
  <div id="parent">
    <Child v-for="array in arrays" :key="array" :child-name="array"></Child>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import data from '../assets/file.json'
import Child from './Child'

export default {
  name: 'Parent',
  components: {
    Child
  },
  computed: {
    arrays() {
      return Object.keys(data)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**This is the child .vue file, it needs to read only the objects into every single array**

```
<template>
  <div id="child">
    {{ child-name }}
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: 'Child',
  props: {
    child-name: String
  }
}
</script>
```

Thanks y'all.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that when you have a prop containing dashes (`-`), you need to use camelCase in your JS, since a variable name cannot contain a dash. Then, you can have both the name and the array *(without the need for an `Object.xx()`)* in your `v-for` by using:

```
v-for="(array, name) in arrays"
```

### Demo

```js
const dataFromFile = {firstArray:[{id:1,name:"Lucas"},{id:2,name:"Michael"}],secondArray:[{id:1,name:"Maria"},{id:2,name:"Taylor"}]};

Vue.component('Child', {
  template: '#child-template',
  props: {
    childName: String,
    childArray: Array
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#parent',
  data() {
    return {
      arrays: dataFromFile
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.21/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
  <Child
    v-for="(array, name) in arrays" :key="array"
    :child-name="name" :child-array="array"
  />
</div>

<template id="child-template">
  <div id="child">
    {{ childName }} - {{ childArray }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Oh! The problem was Object.xx().
Your solutions is great and simple, thanks Sir.